# Building a custom query and nested association definitions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to preload a has_many association to a passed in struct and the has_many association of the passed on structs association.

Here is what I'm working with right now:

```
project =
 Repo.get!(Project, id)
 |> Repo.preload([rows: {query, [images: from i in Image, order_by: i.index]}])
```

But this is returning this error:

```
This error may happen when you forget a comma in a list or other container:

    [a, b c, d]

Elixir cannot compile otherwise. Syntax error before: ','
```

This works just fine though:

```
project =
  Repo.get!(Project, id)
  |> Repo.preload([rows: {query, [:images]}])
```

But in this query I'm not able to do the ordering I want on images. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: `[images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)]`?

Comment: Yep, That was it. Thanks! I thought that the parenthesis in this case are optional? I guess not.

Comment: They are optional in general but required here because of the ambiguity I described in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression

```
[images: from i in Image, order_by: i.index]
```

is ambiguous because of the comma. It can either be interpreted as:

```
[images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)]
```

or as:

```
[images: from(i in Image), order_by: i.index]
```

You need to add explicit parentheses to resolve the ambiguity. In this case, you want:

```
[images: from(i in Image, order_by: i.index)]
```